# How to @Validate unique username in spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

Let's assume that I have a form where I might submit `username(@NaturalId)` and `password` for a new user.

I would like to add the user with a unique `username`. How can I use `@Valid` annotations to validate this constraint? And if username is not unique how can I display this information in jsp via `<form:error/>`?

Answer (score 30):

AFAIK there isn't an annotation to do this. You have two options

One, create a custom validator annotation. [Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints) is a very good example. Make a call to your DAO class and check the availability in the validator implementation

```
    public boolean isValid(String object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {

    return userDAO.userNameAvailable(object); //some method to check username availability
    }
```

**OR**

Set unique = true on your property in your entity class.

```
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userName;
```

But this will not work with @valid, instead throw an exception on persistence. You have to use an appropriate logic to handle that.

The first solution isn't fool proof. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495368/unique-constraint-with-jpa-and-bean-validation) answer on SO.

The second will will never fail.

**UPDATE**

As NimChimpsky commented, using both together will be a concrete solution.

Comment: I'd recommend using both methods

Comment: Well, after digging a bit I feel that the second one is better :) It will never fail unlike the first one.

Comment: um, well that relies on exception handling for when a user inputs a pre existing username, I woul dvalidate user input before trying to persist

Comment: what if there is a concurrent transaction with the same username??

Comment: thats is very unlikely, but it is why I said both methods should used. The column shoul dbe unique, but that does not stop you vaidating input.

Comment: How solve the problem of the update of object? The userDAO.userNameAvailable(object) would return false. I didn't find so far a smart solution if the validation annotation is on the String field username. In fact in this way I cannot get the id of the object and check if it's an update (ok) or a new insert (ko). thanks

Answer (score 4):

JSR-303 does not support what you want (something like a `@Unique` constraint). You have to write you own validator. How can this be done is explained here: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AccessingtheHibernateSessionwithinaConstraintValidator

But before doing that make sure you read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3499111/1981720

And this sentence from the previous article:

> The reason @Unique is not part of the built-in constraints is the fact
>   that accessing the Session/EntityManager during a valiation is opening
>   yourself up for potenital phantom reads.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UserDetailsService prepared spring class, extend and customize it :

```
@Service
public class LoginDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, Serializable {

    @Autowired
    LoginService loginService;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if (username == "" || username.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s is invalid!", username));
        }
        Login login = loginService.find(username);
        if (login == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s does not exist!", username));
        }
        if (!loginService.scheduleChecking(login.getScheduled())) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s is not authorized this time!", username));
        }
      //....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way to find a Unique User name. You Have to use Native Query to perform the Particular Task.

**You have to perform this query on your repository interface**

> @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM customers_details WHERE username = :username
> , nativeQuery = true)
> public List findEmaiList(@Param("username ") String username ,
> @Param("id") Long id);

You can get similar data from the query and pass validation whatever you want.
you can also create a separate Unique API for your convenience.
You can also find different Unique parameters like Email or Mobile using this query