# Add a Custom message for the Unique Constraints in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

```
@Entity @Table(name="users",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"})})
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Column(unique = true,name = "email")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.email}")
    @Email(message = "{Pattern.email}")
    @Size(min=10, max=50)
    private String email;

    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; } 
}
```

I have the message.properties file which is working fine

```
 NotNull.email = Email is required

 Pattern.email = Enter a valid email address
```

can i add another field in the message.properties file like

```
 Unique.email = Email already exits
```

and give this Unique.email to the

```
@Column(unique = true,name = "email",message="{Unique.email}")
```

I know, we cannot keep message="{Unique.email}" in the above line.

but how can we give "Unique.email" to the above column in order to get the custom error message

??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User defined annotation "@Unique" in the model User.java

```
@Column(unique = true,name = "email")
@Unique(message = "{Unique.email}")
private String email;
```

message.properties

```
Unique.email = Email id already exists
```

Unique.java

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Constraint(validatedBy = UserUniqueValidator.class)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Unique {
    String message();
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

UserUniqueValidator.java

```
import com.User;
import com.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class UserUniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Unique,String> {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Unique unique) {
        unique.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (userService != null && userService.existsByEmail(email,User.class)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```
public interface UserService {
    public boolean existsByEmail(String email,Class clazz);
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
import com.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl extends UserRepository implements UserService  {

    @Override
    public boolean existsByEmail(String email, Class clazz) {
        return super.existsByEmail(email,clazz);
    } 

}
```

UserRepository.java

```
public class UserRepository {
  public boolean existsByEmail(String email, Class className) {
      Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(className,"userEmail");
      criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("email",email));
      if(criteria.list().size() == 0){
            return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: for this solution , you must use 'find' in database , it's wrong !

Comment: @saeedeh What's your Idea to avoid "find" use for this solution?

Comment: @Semantic How can I use this Annotation for more tables? Do I need to create separate implementation for all validators?

Comment: @Semantic This implementation throws a validation error on the update of record also. How to solve that?

Comment: @GreenROBO you should skip own id on update request.

Comment: @Maharramoff - thank you for your suggestion. It has been two years and I don't really remember which project was it. :)

Comment: Beware of phantom reads while checking that stuff : @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17105044/390462

Answer (score 4):

In your UserRepository File

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
      Boolean existsByEmail(String email);
}
```

In your controller file

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

if(userRepository.existsByEmail(pass_email_HERE)) {
        throw new YourCustomExceptionException("CUSTOM_ERROR_MESSAGE");
    }
```

Comment: Hmm better is to surround the method with try/catch blocks, catching the DataIntegrityViolationException and add the original to your customized business logic exception as second parameter : 
`try {...} catch(DataIntegrityViolationExceptiondiveException diveException) { logger.error(diveException.getMessage()); 
throw new YourCustomExceptionException("CUSTOM_ERROR_MESSAGE", diveException); }` With this usage, you does not lost the cause of the previous exception.

Comment: The best way is just to add a try/catch block inside the call of your service layer inside your controller and raise a binding error if a DataIntegrityViolationException is thrown, or any other exception of your backend services. @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16172658/390462

Answer (score 1):

I resolve similar problem in Spring Boot I Hope It will help u.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(value = {DataIntegrityViolationException.class})
protected ResponseEntity<JSONObject> handleConflict(DataIntegrityViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    result.appendField("result", false);
    String errorMessage = "";

    org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException exDetail =
            (org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException) ex.getCause();

    errorMessage = fieldCnvrt(exDetail.getConstraintName()) + " birden fazla aynı değer içeremez!";


    result.appendField("message", errorMessage);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).body(result);
}

private String fieldCnvrt(String field) {
    switch (field) {
        case "username":
            field = "Kullanıcı Adı";
            break;
        case "email":
            field = "Email";
            break;
        case "short_name":
            field = "Kısaltımış Ad";
            break;
        case "name":
            field = "Ad";
            break;
    }

    return field;
}
```

}