# unique=true validation with a message - java

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to know how can use a validation with a message for unique=true in my entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

...

@NotEmpty(message = "it cannot be empty")
@Column(name="identification_number", nullable=false, unique=true)
// a message with (message = "the identification number already exist") but i'dont know how implement
private String numeroIdentificacion;

...
```

Comment: I guess you will you have to write your custom validator and own constraint annotation.

Comment: `@Table(name="employees", uniqueConstraints = {
      @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "numeroIdentificacion", name = "uniqueNumero")}
)` Did you try something like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a Custom message for the Unique Constraints in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466545/add-a-custom-message-for-the-unique-constraints-in-hibernate)

Comment: @Govind Because it is with db columns you need to use the db column name and not the java entity name : `@Column(name="identification_number", nullable=false, unique=true)` => `columnNames = "identification_number"` in your constraint definition inside the `@Table` annotation.

Comment: The best way is just to add a try/catch block inside the call of your service layer inside your controller and raise a binding error if a DataIntegrityViolationException is thrown, or any other exception of your backend services. @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16172658/390462

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Column(unique= true)
 @Unique(message="duplicate message")
```

will give the validation message.

Comment: Where your `@Unique` annotation is coming from ? 
There is no `@Unique` annotation in JPA or Hibernate as much as I know. 

So, if you are creating one with your service layer, beware of phantom reads (Serialization level while JPA transactions are the only way to go safely here).