# How to Validate in Spring boot for Duplicate Entry for email unique type column constrain

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to validate for the unique column email I Face Below Error

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'example@gmail.com' for key 'UK_ctgb3irqvos5u342ejnxy7gq8'
```

And I use the below code

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Id
private long id;
@NotEmpty(message = "Please Enter Your Name")
private String username;
@Column(unique = true)
@NotEmpty(message = "Please Enter Your Email Address")
@Email(message = "Please Enter Valid Email Address")
private String useremail;
@Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 10, message = "Please Enter Your Mobile No")
private String usermobile;
@Size(min = 8, message = "Please enter atleast 8 digit password")
private String userpassword;
@Size(min = 8, message = "Your Password is Not Match")
private String confirmpassword;
private LocalDate registerdate;
private boolean status;
private String lastipaddress;
private LocalDate lastlogin;
```

Please find the

Comment: It (unique column constraint) works! How to do it in spring-boot: in your "end point"/service, you'd catch (ideally) `org.springframew...DataAccessException`, (inspect &) handle that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3495368/592355 ,  https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+data+exception+translator

Comment: I already checked but not working 
I ask after searching lot of doc and website and on youtube and many more

Comment: You aren't validating anything in your code... Also the only sure way is to handle that exception, even if you check there could be ( a corner case but still) a time that a user registers twice on the same moment, both see no emailaddress and try to insert a record, 1 succeeds, the other will fail.